# Evaluating a Struts value within a JSTL tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, el, ognl

I'm currently developing a language pack for an application built on Struts 2. The language pack is defined in a properties file which will be accessed by the frontend JSP via JSTL (FMT tags).

I'm trying to achieve something like String formatting, i.e. inserting a Struts value into a sentence string retrieved via an FMT tag.

What's defined in my properties file:

```
userprofile.link.text = <a href="{0}">Click here</a> to view your profile page.
```

And from the JSP side,

```
<fmt:message key="userprofile.link.text">
   <fmt:param value='/profile/<s:property value="userBean.id"/>'/>
</fmt:message>
```

However, the link does not render correctly. How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. JSTL uses `${}` (EL);
2. Struts2 ValueStack is exposed to JSTL through the [StrutsRequestWrapper](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/StrutsRequestWrapper.html):

   > All Struts requests are wrapped with this class, which provides simple JSTL accessibility. This is because JSTL works with request attributes, so this class delegates to the value stack [...]

Then this should be enough:

```xml
<fmt:message key="userprofile.link.text">
    <fmt:param value='/profile/${userBean.id}'/>
</fmt:message>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a million. (: Will check out the link as well.