# Struts 2 OGNL . Not able to retrieve data using %{} syntax

Tags: jsp, struts2, el, ognl, struts-tags

I have developed a simple Struts 2 project.but when I am trying to retrieve the data from valuestack I am not getting any data. Basically %{} syntax is not recognized while the page is getting served.

My Index.jsp

```xml
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="justwork.action">
<input type="text" name="name" value="Xarvis">
<input type="submit" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My struts.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd"> 
<package name="TestFramework" extends="struts-default" >
<action name="justwork" class="org.pranab.actions.OGNLTest">
<result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

my OGNLTest.java

```java
 package org.pranab.actions;
 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
 public class OGNLTest {

    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String execute(){
     return "success";
        }}
```

finally my success.jsp

```xml
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
       <h2>SUCCESS</h2>

         <s:property default="%{name}" value="name"/>
         <br>
%{name}
</body>
</html>
```

Output on Submit:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjO1m.png)

Is there a requirement of a switch in strust.xml or properties to enable the %{} syntax??

Answer (score 0):

You're making confusion:

- `%{}` is [OGNL's expression evaluation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26049203/1654265).
- What you want outside of the tag is `${}`, [which is JSP EL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34265860/1654265)
- [JSP EL is not escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23367430/1654265) and is very basic when compared to Struts2 tags or JSTL tags. Avoid using it.

---

#### EDIT

[`default` attribute is of type String](https://struts.apache.org/docs/property.html), not Object like `value`, hence it won't be evaluated.

Put a static String in it.

Comment: Thank Andrea for input. But when I am using %{} inside the struts 2 tags then also it's not working.

Comment: Yes that's the value .... but suppose I provided the value attribute with another property that doesn't exist in ValueStack. like <s:property default="%{name}" value="lastName" > . Then as value doesn't exist in value stack then my default attribute should take over . But then also the output from the tag is : %{name}

Comment: yes,default attribute is of strig type, hence I am using OGNL EL expression to force retrival of value from valuestack so that my default attribute will store a dynamic value instead of static one. That's the whole  point of using EL against the default attribute